# Having trouble beginning to create a dark fade upon hover of an image

Tags: html, css, css-transitions, fade

I want to have very dark fade overlay an image, display some text, and offer a button that links to another site.  I presume the latter (displaying text and adding the button)  is relitively simple.  However, I really don't know where to start utilizing CSS to affectively have this 'dark fade' appear on hover.  Could anyone help me with the CSS to do this? Below is the HTML and CSS I have now.  It's very basic.  As I mentioned, I tried a few things, but non of them came close.

HTML:

```
<div class = "CoverPhoto">
<img src="Facebook%20Cover.png">
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.CoverPhoto{position: Absolute; top: 12%; Left 15%;}
```

What would be the next step?
Again, any insight into this problem would be extremely helpful.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a `pseudo element` on the container on hover that has a background of `background:rgba(0,0,0,0.7)` which will make the image darker, we just make it take full width and position it correctly with `position:absolute`. As for the text and the button we do the same thing we just gotta make sure its wrapper is a child of the container.

(I've added some effects so the text fades in from the left with `transform`)

[**Here**](http://codepen.io/Ayeetu/pen/obegJq?editors=110) is an example how it looks when it's done.

HTML:

```
<div class = "CoverPhoto">

  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/300/300/">
  <div class="content">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolore culpa, molestiae ducimus magni blanditiis nemo deserunt totam quo iste. At?</p>
    <button>Click me!</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.CoverPhoto {
  width: 400px;
  position: relative;
}
.CoverPhoto:hover:after {
  opacity: 1;
}
.CoverPhoto:hover .content {
  transform: translateX(0);
  opacity: 1;
}
.CoverPhoto:after {
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in;
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  padding: 0;
  z-index: 2;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  opacity: 0;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
}
.CoverPhoto img {
  width: 100%;
}

.content {
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in;
  transform: translateX(-100%);
  z-index: 10;
  color: #fff;
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

well am not quite sure what are you asking but, i think u want to make a button look darker when the mouse hover,

In my opinion the easy way to do this is by creating the image in such a way that it has 2 images assuming Facebook logo  which is 200px by 200px and the image you can create is 400px by 200px where the height has 200px extra containing the logo with black overlay on it. Than hover will show the darker side. Like this :

Html

```
<div class="image"></div>
```

Css

```
.image { 
background-image:url{image.gif}
width:200px
height:200px
} 

.image:hover{
background-position:0 -200px;
}
```

I hope this might help i wrote it with my iphone sorry for that ,

Comment: Note that its simple with no transition effects, try it using transition effects after understanding it